# Что хранится/сохраняется в функциональном программировании?

Tags: функциональное-программирование

Какие данные подлежит хранению в функциональной парадигме? Входящие данные как неизменяемые константы? А результаты вычислений можно не сохранять и считать их всякий раз при возникновении необходимости, или это решается для каждого случая индивидуально?
 И еще, данные, поступающие на обработку в программу, - аргументы функций, это функция? Всё есть функция? Их обязательно оборачивают в функцию (если писать функционально в нефункциональных ЯП), или это просто константы, которые есть переменные и их можно указывать через присваивание ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В самой-самой теоретической и оторванной от жизни версии функциональной парадигмы - [лямбда-исчислении](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) - и правда все есть функция. Там даже числа реализованы как функции.

В более практических вариантах ФП кроме функций есть еще и значения. Точнее, слово "кроме" тут не вполне правильное, потому что функция - это разновидность значения. Любое значение в ФП является константой, вопрос "сохранять или не сохранять промежуточные результаты" перед программистом на функциональных языках не стоит, потому что это задача транслятора. Вместо этого программист решает нужно ли присваивать промежуточному результату имя.

Переменных в ФП нет. То, что кажется знаком присваивания - это лишь связывание некоторого значения с некоторым именем чтобы к нему можно было обратиться из другого места. Например:

```hs
pi = 3.141592653589793

toRad x = x * pi / 180
toDeg x = x * 180 / pi
```

Здесь значение 3.141592653589793 оказывается связанным с именем `pi` (и становится тем самым именованной константой), а затем используется в функциях `toRad` и `toDeg`.

Более сложный вариант:

```
cosDeg x = cos y
    where y = toRad x
```

Здесь `y` - локальная константа.

Принципиальное отличие от переменной - значение нельзя изменять! Если с именем `y` связано значение `toDeg x` - то переприсвоить другое значение уже не получится.

Теперь про ввод и вывод. Основным для "чистого" ФП является режим [REPL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REPL), когда пользователь запускает интерпретатор и вводит ему выражения, а тот вычисляет результат и отвечает:

```
> cosDeg 0
< 1.0
> cosDeg 90
< 0.0
```

В случае же необходимости скомпилировать нормальную программу приходится жертвовать чистотой языка и вводить элементы императивного программирования. Так, в языке Haskell для этих целей существует монада IO:

```
main = do
  xs <- getLine
  let x = read xs
  putStrLn $ show $ cosDeg x
```

При этом система типов устроена так, что императивный код может вызывать как другой императивный, так и чистые функции. А вот чистые функции могут вызывать только другие чистые функции.

---

Отмечу также, что кроме лямбда-исчисления в ФП можно использовать комбинаторную логику, более того - комбинаторная логика появилась исторически первой. Но сейчас использование комбинаторной логики с нормальным программированием имеет мало общего (к примеру, в ней нет не только переменных - но даже констант, любая программа представляется как одно большое выражение которое нужно вычислить).

---

Применительно к императивным языкам, выражение "писать в функциональном стиле" означает "не использовать переменные и обходиться без побочных эффектов". К примеру, вот этот код на javascript написан в функциональном стиле (кроме последней строчки):

```js
const items = [1, 2, 3];
const squares = items.map(x => x*x);
const sum = squares.reduce((x, y) => x+y, 0);
console.log(sum);
```

А вот этот - на функциональный стиль совсем не тянет, хоть и маскируется под него:

```
const items = [1, 2, 3];
const squares = [];
items.forEach(x => squares.push(x*x));
let sum = 0;
squares.forEach(x => sum += x);
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ. 
Я пытаюсь прояснить, для себя, следующую штуку: программа существует для выдачи потребителю/клиенту обработанных данных. В императивной парадигме, это измененное состояние в моменте времени. А в функциональной парадигме? Мы ведь тоже выдаем клиенту измененное состояние, с той разницей, что для нас измененное состояние не является целью. Так вот, мы храним где-то это измененное состояние (результаты работы функций), или получаем эти результаты вычисляя их каждый раз как приходит запрос?

Comment: @sorda нет, клиенту выдается не измененное состояние, а ответ на запрос, его вовсе не обязательно нужно хранить.

Comment: Для полной ясности уточню, с вашего позволения, а Flux / Redux - библиотеки хранящие состояние для отдачи клиенту это все только для императивщиков JS? В ФП, программа не хранит свое состояние и ответ на запрос считается каждый раз? Я имею ввиду: с клиента приходит запрос, мы идем в базу за данным, которые константы, производим над ними операции чистыми функциями, в соответствии с запросом клиента и отдаем результат, который кэшируется?

Comment: Состояние это промежуточный результат, который можно хранить или нет, в зависимости от сложности вычислений (чем сложнее - много источников и входящих данных; сложные операции над данными, -  тем больше в сторону хранить), я правильно понял?